# When is the number of waves in a raid determined?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

If I start a raid in hard mode then immediately switch to easy after the raid starts, do I get 7 waves or only 3?  When is the number of waves in a raid determined? Is it when the raid starts, or is it recalculated at the start of each wave?

I looked through the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raid), but I didn't find anything definitive. I plan on trying it out in my world sometime soon, but I haven't found any pillager captains recently.

The reason I'm asking is because I want totems of undying, but my kids play on the same server and they want to join in on the raid as well. Setting it to easy mode will hopefully result in them having a higher chance of survival until it's over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally has some time to find a pillager captain and start a raid.

I started the raid in hard difficulty. After the raid started (beginning of first wave), I switched the difficulty to easy. There were a total of 7 waves which corresponds to the hard difficulty. This means that **the number of waves is determined at the beginning of the raid**. Switching the difficulty does not change the number of waves.

Comment: You may want to press the check mark to accept your own answer as correct, to help others know what worked. You can change this if a better answer comes along.